# Send NSArray to NSTableView

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsarray, nstableview

What is the easiest way to send the data stored in an NSArray to a NSTableView and display it line by line?

For example:
NSArray has data [a, b, c]

I want the NSTableView to say:

a

b

c

The NSTableView only needs 1 column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't "send" things to NSTableView. NSTableView asks you for things. It does so via the NSTableViewDataSource protocol. So all you need to do is implement the two required methods from that (-numberOfRowsInTableView: and -tableView:objectValueForTableColumn:row:), and connect the tableview's data source outlet to your object.

Documentation for NSTableViewDataSource is here: https://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Protocols/NSTableDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Thanks. But where do I implement these? And how do I point the NSTableView to an object?

Comment: In any class you want (for simple cases, probably your app delegate), and the same way you connect any other outlet in interface builder (if you don't know how to do this, I suggest googling for a basic Cocoa tutorial. It's pretty much impossible to write Cocoa apps without connecting outlets)

Answer (score -1):

You need to explore UITableViewDelegate and UiTableViewDataSource delegate methods:

```
#pragma mark --- Table View Delegate Methods ----------------------------
//Handles the selection of a cell in a table view
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}

//Defines the number of sections in a table view
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

//Defines the header of the section in the table view
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return nil; 
}

//Defines the number of rows in each section
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 1;
}

//Defines the content of the table view cells
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [myDataArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];//<-pay attention to this line

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Just realised my answer involves UIKit rather than whatever's used on OSX, but I'm sure the principles still apply.

Comment: To some extent the principles apply to NSTableView, but only in view-based mode.